# Is it safe to use Turkish Airlines now?

Tags: safety, turkey, turkish-airlines

Given what is happening in Turkey at the moment, is it advisable using Turkish Airlines with a 2-hour transit in Turkey to my final destination; Copenhagen?

Comment: I changed the tags; the [tag:airport-transfer] tag is for questions about ground transportation to and from airports.  However, your question is opinion-based and will likely be closed, unless you change it to something that has an objective answer.

Answer (score 1):

The current warning from the U.S. State Department states:

> The U.S. Department of State warns U.S. citizens of increased threats from terrorist groups throughout Turkey and to avoid travel to southeastern Turkey. In light of the July 15 coup attempt and the resulting potential for interruptions to travel and daily life, we suggest U.S. citizens reconsider travel to Turkey at this time.

That would imply that, if you can avoid an Istanbul transit, you should do so.

Comment: Istanbul is nowhere near the war zone, and there is an increased risk of terrorist attacks in the United States. But no one suggests you reconsider your trip to Dallas!

Comment: @pnuts I think "more to come" is guaranteed. Terrorism is not a solved problem by any means. My (poorly made) point was about the State Department's travel advisories occasionally verging toward paranoia.

Comment: I'm sure plenty of countries would ask their citizens to reconsider their trips to Dallas.  This is the first travel warning the U.S. has put out specifically suggesting that U.S. citizens reconsider travel to the country, and it came as the U.S. withdrew family members of all military personnel in Turkey, and placed family members of diplomatic personnel on "voluntary leave".  Obviously no one can make a decision for @Mysterio, but that's as close to a definitive source as I know.